# trouble understanding a while loop in a PHP function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm checking out some code to better understand how it's working (educational purposes), however I'm having trouble understanding a certain function that goes over an array and outputs them into groups by the class they are in.

This is the array:

```
$leerlingen =  array(
    "TIDekorte",
    "TADelange",
    "TICoene",
    "TAFriesmans",
    "BMJanssens",
    "TITomsen",
    "TIAelbrecht",
    "TIVermoortel",
    "TADaelmans"
);
```

This is the function that takes that ordens them by the first two letters of each string:

```
function groupList($array)
{
    $i = 0;
    while($i < count($array))
    {
        $prefix = substr($array[$i], 0, 2);
        echo("<p>Class {$prefix}</p>");
        echo("<ul>");
        while($i < count($array) && substr($array[$i], 0, 2) == $prefix)
        {
            $naam = substr($array[$i++], 2);
            echo("<li>{$naam}</li>");
        }
        echo("</ul>");
    }
}
```

[image: The result of the function]

The part I can't figure out is 
`while($i < count($array) && substr($array[$i], 0, 2) == $prefix){}`

I understand both of the combined conditions seperately, but don't understand them when put together. Could someone explain to me how this while loop works?

Heres all the code spread over 4 .php files

**htmlhead.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>oefn</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
```

**htmlindex.php**

```
<?php

require_once("htmlkop.php");
require_once("functies.php");

$leerlingen =  array(
    "TIDekorte",
    "TADelange",
    "TICoene",
    "TAFriesmans",
    "BMJanssens",
    "TITomsen",
    "TIAelbrecht",
    "TIVermoortel",
    "TADaelmans"
);

echo("<h1>De lijst</h1>");
echo("<ul>");
foreach($leerlingen as $ll)
{
    echo("<li>{$ll}</li>");
}
echo("</ul>");

sort($leerlingen);

echo("<h1>De gegroepeerde lijst</h1>");

groupList($leerlingen);

require_once("htmlstaart.php");

?>
```

**htmlfunctions.php**

```
<?php

function groupList($array)
{
    $i = 0;
    while($i < count($array))
    {
        $prefix = substr($array[$i], 0, 2);
        echo("<p>Class {$prefix}</p>");
        echo("<ul>");
        while($i < count($array) && substr($array[$i], 0, 2) == $prefix)
        {
            $naam = substr($array[$i++], 2);
            echo("<li>{$naam}</li>");
        }
        echo("</ul>");
    }
}
?>
```

**htmltail.php**

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Can't reproduce your output**](http://viper-7.com/MRyz0i) Are you sure this is the function, which prints this exact array, exactly like this?

Comment: Yes , this is exact array and function that are being used , the given results are from when I run it.

Comment: As shown above, I can't reproduce your output. So you either have a different array or a different function or there is more code which we don't see.

Comment: uploaded all code the files contain. (edite the name files to english head= kop and tail = staart)

Comment: Now it makes more sense if you sort the array first. So basically what the inner loop does is, first it assigns the prefix (first 2 characters), it just loops through all values with the same prefix until it hits anther one, and then the inner loop stops and and you enter the outer loop again and print a new ul list.

Comment: Ahh I think i'm starting to get it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly.

```
while($i < count($array))
```

is just a regular while loop and you can think of

```
&& substr($array[$i], 0, 2) == $prefix
```

as an if statement so this can be rewritten as

```
while($i < count($array)) 
    if ( substr($array[$i], 0, 2) == $prefix )
```

It will compare the first two characters of the array to the prefix and if they are equal only then will it print the string.

**EDIT:**

```
"TIDekorte",
"TICoene",
"TITomsen",
"TIAelbrecht",
"TIVermoortel",

"TADelange",
"TAFriesmans",
"TADaelmans",

"BMJanssens"
```

I've rearranged what the output should be based on the string you submitted.